# Создание слайдера - Java

Tags: java, android, slider

Посоветуйте плагин или как создавать слайдер изображение на языке Java.
Необходим слайдер из 5-6 картинок,.
Слайдер такого типа: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не надо ссылок на левые ресурсы. Разместите сразу картинку. Если у вас андроид, то (я не смотрел ссылку) то вам скорее всего нужен ViewPager

Comment: Спасибо, вроде то,что необходимо.

Answer (score 1):

com.github.paolorotolo - библиотека, посмотрите её на гитхабе